# Correct way to post a comment

Tags: discussion

It has happened to me on more than one occasion: when I make a comment, the reference to the person who gave me the answer does not appear.

Example:

If it was Bill who gave me the answer, I post my comment to the answer beginning with @Bill followed by the text of my comment. However, all I see is the text.

Why does this happen?

Comment: If you are the first commenter in an answer, then this is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020).